# Comparing means and ranking most impactful factors

Tags: mean

I have a beginner question. I am trying to find most impactful factors for mean value when comparing two data sets to each other.

Week 1:

[image: Buyers week 1]

Week 2:

[image: Buyers week 2]

I can state from this simple example that there were two major factors impacting the cost per unit change (from 1.90 to 2.09).

1. Buyer 1 had higher cost and cost per unit
2. Buyer 4 bought less units which increased the overall CPU compared
   to week 1

I am trying to figure out formula to calculate this for hundreds of rows and rank each buyer who impacted the change the most, however cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is under the assumption of "small enough" changes to linearize your equation and calculate the change in time as follows:

Your target is the average cost per unit (1.9 in week 1), we'll designate it $y_t$.
and you have the costs and units sold for every buyer that we'll designate $c_{i,t}, u_{i,t}$ respectively, where $i$ designates the buyer.

Therefore:

$y_t = \frac{\sum_ic_{i,t}}{\sum_iu_{i,t}}$

$y_{t+1} = \frac{\sum_ic_{i,t+1}}{\sum_iu_{i,t+1}}$

we can change variables to proportion by dividing by $y_t$:

$Y_{t+1} = \frac{\sum_ic_{i,t+1}}{y_t\sum_iu_{i,t+1}}$

from here it follows that by definition $Y_t = y_t/y_t = 1$
and now linearize in every variable $u,c$ by taking the first term of the Taylor expansion:

$\frac{dY_{t}}{dc_{i,t}} =\frac{1}{y_t\sum_iu_{i,t}}$

$\frac{dY_{t}}{du_{i,t}} =-\frac{y_t\sum_ic_{i,t}}{(y_t\sum_iu_{i,t})^2} = -\frac{\sum_ic_{i,t}}{y_t(\sum_iu_{i,t})^2}$

And finally, we write the Taylor expansion:

$Y_{t+1} \approx 1 + \sum_i\frac{1}{y_t\sum_iu_{i,t+1}}(c_{i,t+1} - c_{i,t}) - \sum_i\frac{\sum_ic_{i,t}}{y_t(\sum_iu_{i,t})^2}(u_{i,t+1} - u_{i,t})$

since we want the change in quantities and not the absolute we subtract 1 ($Y_t$) from both sides, and notice that the sums are just total cost and total units sold and rewrite the equation:

$\Delta Y_{t} \approx \sum_i\frac{1}{y_tsold_{total}}\Delta c_{i,t} - \sum_i\frac{cost_{total}}{y_tsold_{total}^2}\Delta u_{i,t}$

Applying this to the data in your question:
$cost_{total} = 950$

$sold_{total} = 500$

$y_t = 1.9$

$\Delta u_{1,1} = 0, \Delta u_{2,1} = 0, \Delta u_{3,1} = 0, \Delta u_{4,1} = -100 $

$\Delta c_{1,1} = 10, \Delta c_{2,1} = 0, \Delta c_{3,1} = 0, \Delta c_{4,1} = -125 $

Applying the formulas ($\Delta_1$ is the change due to buyer 1):

$\Delta_1 = \frac{1}{1.9*500}\Delta c_{1,1} - \frac{950}{1.9*500^2}\Delta c_{1,1} = 0.02$

$\Delta_2 = \frac{1}{1.9*500}\Delta c_{2,1} - \frac{950}{1.9*500^2}\Delta c_{2,1} = 0$

$\Delta_3 = \frac{1}{1.9*500}\Delta c_{3,1} - \frac{950}{1.9*500^2}\Delta u_{3,1} = 0$

$\Delta_4 = \frac{1}{1.9*500}\Delta c_{4,1} - \frac{950}{1.9*500^2}\Delta u_{4,1} = -0.131 +0.25 = 0.118$

so to summarize we can see that the change in cost of buyer 1 increased the total CPU by about 2%, and the decrease in units bought by buyer 4 increased the total cost by about 12%. this can be broken down to a 13% decrease due to decrease in total price payed by buyer 4 and 25% increase due to decrease in units bought.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply, very detailed explanation. It wasn't as easy as I thought it to be.